# delayed_job: How do you set the queue on a custom job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Super simple question, but I can't find how to do it anywhere in the docs or code.

How do you queue a job into a specific queue?

Given code like this:

```
CustomJob = Struct.new(:arg1, :arg2) do
  def perform
    # Do things
  end
end

Delayed::Job.enqueue CustomJob.new(:thing1, :thing2)
```

How do I enqueue into a specific queue? Seems like it should either be passed as an option to `Delayed::Job.enqueue` or defined on the job obj definition like `max_attempts`. In a model method you would pass that arg to `handle_asyncronously` method.

Comment: The README says you can pass the option with `queue: 'queue_name'`. Does that work?

Comment: Yeah Zetetic you are right. I was looking at the 3.0.4 docs because that is the version I am using. Looks like in v4 you can pass queue directly to `Delayed::Job.enqueue` but not in v3.